# ansible: how can I copy files to hosts depending on group membership?

Tags: copy, ansible

how can I copy files to hosts depending on group membership?

i have no idea how to do that. the only thing i can think of is something like that:

```
hostsfile:
[webserver]
hostA
[dbserver]
hostB

files:
webfile.zip
dbfile.zip

- copy:
    src: one of the files
    dest: /opt
    owner: '{owner}}'
    group: '{group}}'
    Fashion: 0644
  when: groupname == webserver then file: webfile.zip OR groupname == dbserver then dbfile.zip
```

but (as far as I know) it can't work.

Comment: I think that in this situation, 2 tasks is far more clear and precise.

Answer (score 0):

With Ansible there is usually several ways to do things, so really depends on what your end result of this playbook will do, and if you will expand on this later.  However, one way you could accomplish this would be by using group variables (host variables could do this same thing, but is set up differently).

## INVENTORY_FILE.txt

```
[WEBSERVERS]
hostname1

[DBSERVERS]
hostname2

[WEBSERVERS:vars]
file=webserver_file.txt
destination=/web/server/path

[DBSERVERS:vars]
file=dbserver_file.txt
destination=/db/server/path
```

## PLAYBOOK.yml

```
- name: Deployment Files to Hosts
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    owner: user_name
    group: group_name

  tasks:
  - name: loop through items based on group_vars
    copy:
      src: '{{ file }}'
      dest: '{{ destination }}'
      owner: '{{ owner }}'
      group: '{{ group }}'
      mode: 644
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use group vars for this. when the playbook is running against webservers the webserver.yml will be loaded and the same for dbserver :

group_vars/webserver.yml

```
file: webfile.zip
```

group_vars/dbserver.yml

```
file: dbfile.zip
```

task.yml

```
- copy:
    src: "{{ file }}"
    dest: /opt
    owner: "{{ owner }}"
    group: "{{ group }}"
    Fashion: 0644
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepare in advance an array containing the file locations, then use it in a `with_first_found` lookup. The following can be used to select a host-tailored resource, a group (with no priority) or a default one.

This works well with groups without common hosts, i.e.: `prod`, `test`, `dev`.

```
- hosts: all                                                                     
  tasks:                                                                         
    - name: create group paths array                                                     
      set_fact:                                                                  
        group_paths: "{{ group_paths | default([]) + [ 'files/' + item ] }}"            
      with_items: "{{ group_names }}"                                            
    - name: show first found based on group                                         
      debug:                                                                     
        msg: "found {{ item }}"                                                     
      with_first_found:                                                             
        - "files/{{ inventory_hostname }}"                                          
        - "{{ group_paths }}"                                                         
        - "files/default"
```